# How are shocks generated in a linear one-dimensional lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, acoustics, crystals, shock-waves

I am struggling to understand shocks in a one-dimensional lattice. Say I have a one dimensional lattice with a linear spring constant $k$ and lattice spacing $a$. If the particles in the lattice has mass $m$ then my speed of sound $c$ is $$c=a\cdot\sqrt\frac km$$ That is a small disturbance will propagate with speed $c$. Now if I move one of the end particles in my lattice at a speed greater than $c$, I should incite a shockwave? Will the dynamics then be governed by the Hugoniot relations?

I guess my confusion is as to how a shock forms if the system is linear... is it because the compressibility behind the shock becomes nonlinear such that the higher levels of loading propagate faster resulting in a shock front? I can see how a nonlinear lattice will result in shocks but I'm struggling to see the picture with linear lattices.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Your answer to yourself is correct: $k$ is a function of density, and when the density increases too much, $k$ will change and the speed of sound will increase

Comment: @OfekGillon thanks for your comment. How can I derive the k is a function of density if k is linear between two masses?

Comment: @curious_being you can't derive it a priori, it depends on the material's equation of state. Although some people try to use DFT methods to calculate a material's EoS, there is more work to be done until we can say this method is accurate... (I'm not from the field but that's what I heard. A DFT expert may tell otherwise)

Comment: @curious_being If you want nonlinear behavior from your model, you need a nonlinear model. So make $k$ a nonlinear function of the particle separation.

Comment: @alephzero so does this mean that linear systems cannot support shocks?